# Como exibir texto com a função OnMouseOver()

Tags: javascript

Estou aprendendo mexer com `javascript`, e olhando [esse snippet](https://codepen.io/fabiogoodoy/pen/wgipx) que mostra o mapa do Brasil e seus estados me surgiu uma duvida. Como posso fazer aparecer o nome do estado ao colocar o mouse por cima do estado em `javascript`?

Exemplo do que eu quero atingir:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: MouseUp é o evento que ocorre quando você "solta" um dos botões do mouse. MouseDown é disparado quando você pressiona um dos botões. O que você quer é [onmouseover](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onmouseover)

Comment: Como o amigo falou ou vc usa o onmouseover do JS, ou nesse caso do mapa o que eu indicaria é o `:hover` do próprio CSS

Comment: @WilliamJohnAdamTrindade sim é bem isso mesmo, mas como faço para aparecer o nome?

Comment: @hunterxhunter Você entendeu o Snippet? Ele usa o JQuery ,evento `hover` sobre um link que tem como background um SVG. Você quer fazer a mesma coisa? Pelo que eu vi no seu exemplo você usa uma imagem.

Comment: @WilliamJohnAdamTrindade o exemplo é so para explicar melhor o que quero atingir, porém utilizando o snippet mesmo.

Answer (score 2):

Você poderia usar 2 eventos:

- `mouseover`: mostrar ao passar o mouse
- `mouseout`: esconder ao tirar o mouse

Vale lembrar que os dois eventos acima não possuem *bubble* (não se propagam, cada elemento filho "herdará" o evento do pai). Por exemplo, no código abaixo aplico `mouseover` apenas na div-pai, porém a div-filho também chamará a função ao passar o mouse:

```js
var p = document.getElementById("pai");

p.onmouseover = function(e){
  console.clear();
  console.log(e.target.id);
}
```

```css
#pai{
   width: 200px;
   height: 100px;
   background: red;
}

#filho{
   width: 100px;
   height: 50px;
   background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="pai">
  pai
  <div id="filho">
     filho
  </div>
</div>
```

Usando os eventos (recomendado):

- `mouseenter`: mostrar ao passar o mouse
- `mouseleave`: esconder ao tirar o mouse

Estes eventos possuem *blubble*, ou seja, é disparado em toda `div` a qual o evento foi atribuído, tendo filhos ou não. No exemplo abaixo, ao passar o mouse também na div-filho, é disparado o evento da div-pai apenas uma vez:

```js
var p = document.getElementById("pai");

p.onmouseenter = function(e){
  console.log(e.target.id);
}
```

```css
#pai{
   width: 200px;
   height: 100px;
   background: red;
}

#filho{
   width: 100px;
   height: 50px;
   background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="pai">
  pai
  <div id="filho">
     filho
  </div>
</div>
```

O exemplo que você lincou na pergunta utiliza o método `.hover` do jQuery. Este método possui duas funções para dois eventos: `mouseenter` e `mouseleave`, nesta ordem:

```
$(seletor).hover(

   function(){
      // função do mouseenter (quando o mouse "entra", passa por cima)
   }
   ,
   function(){
      // função do mouseleave (quando o mouse sai de cima)
   }

);
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
$("#pai").hover(

   function(){
      $(this).css("background", "blue");
   }
   ,
   function(){
      $(this).css("background", "red");
   }

);
```

```css
#pai{
   width: 200px;
   height: 100px;
   background: red;
}

#filho{
   width: 100px;
   height: 50px;
   background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pai">
  pai
  <div id="filho">
     filho
  </div>
</div>
```

### Edit

Como a resposta foi um pouco longa e enquanto eu a estava redigindo, o [título da pergunta foi alterado mudando seu sentido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/316406/revisions), e para responder com o novo título, eu diria que vai depender muito da estrutura do seu código.

Um exemplo simples seria como abaixo, onde eu tenho um `span` com o nome do Estado dentro de uma `div` que seria a área do Estado. Ao passar o mouse sobre a `div`, eu mostro o `span`, ao retirar o mouse, eu o escondo.

Veja que criei dois eventos dentro de um laço aplicando-os a todas as `div`s com a classe `.estado`.

Agora, para montar o mapa do Brasil e aplicar os eventos já é outra questão. No exemplo que você lincou na pergunta, o mapa é montado usando `<svg>` (**[como usar](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_path.asp)**), que é até o mais indicado do que usar uma imagem. Se for usar uma imagem você terá que *mapear* cada Estado usando a tag `<map>` (**[como usar](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp)**).

```js
var estados = document.querySelectorAll('.estado');
for(var x=0; x<estados.length; x++){
   estados[x].onmouseenter = function(){
   
      this.querySelector('span').style.display = 'inline-block';
   
   }

   estados[x].onmouseleave = function(){
   
      this.querySelector('span').style.display = 'none';
   
   }
}
```

```css
.estado{
   width: 300px;
   height: 100px;
   background: blue;
   position: relative;
   margin: 3px;
}

.estado span{
   display: none;
   padding: 5px;
   background: white;
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
Passe o mouse:
<div class="estado">
   <span>Distrito Federal</span>
</div>
<div class="estado">
   <span>São Paulo</span>
</div>
```

### Edit 2

No exemplo acima, quando possui um elemento filho, você pode usar apenas CSS com o seletor `:hover` para alterar o comportamento do elemento filho, sem a necessidade de usar JavaScript. Mas como eu disse, isso dependerá muito da estrutura como você quer montar.

```css
.estado{
   width: 300px;
   height: 100px;
   background: blue;
   position: relative;
   margin: 3px;
}

.estado:hover span{
   display: inline-block;
}

.estado span{
   display: none;
   padding: 5px;
   background: white;
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
Passe o mouse:
<div class="estado">
   <span>Distrito Federal</span>
</div>
<div class="estado">
   <span>São Paulo</span>
</div>
```

**Referências:**

- Eventos:

  - [mouseover](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp)
  - [mouseout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseout.asp)
  - [mouseenter](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseenter.asp)
  - [mouseleave](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseleave.asp)
- [jQuery `.hover`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)
- [CSS :hover](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp)